# sagemaker deep forecaseting file parsing error

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, jsonlines

I am trying out Deep AR fore[Deep AR Forecasting](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/now-available-in-amazon-sagemaker-deepar-algorithm-for-more-accurate-time-series-forecasting/)casting training algorithm. My training job keeps failing with the following error while parsing the jsonlines file:
row: 1) Failure reason
ClientError: Error when parsing json (source: /opt/ml/input/data/train/daily_call_vol_lines.json, row: 1)
I am attaching the file (json) with json lines format I tried with
Any help into why the parser fails on sagemaker side would help!
Pasting the file content:
{
    "TimeStamp": "2017-07-01",
    "Number of Calls": 14
}
{
    "TimeStamp": "2017-07-02",
    "Number of Calls": 62
}
{
    "TimeStamp": "2017-07-03",
    "Number of Calls": 972
}

Answer (score 0):

The format you are using is not supported, each line should be of this form for a json file: `{"start": "2017-07-01", "target": [14, 62, 972, ...]}`. The description of the formats that are supported can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/deepar.html), you can also have a look of this [end-to-end example](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/deepar_electricity/DeepAR-Electricity.ipynb) that generates training data in json format.